# gcc 4.7 and recursive constexpr functions

Tags: c++, recursion, c++11, constexpr, gcc4.7

I'm playing a little bit with `constexpr` recursion and try to see how it is compiled and I don't understand under which circumstances `gcc` choose to calculate the recursion at compile time or at run time.

I'm using the following factorial calculation code :

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr unsigned int factorial(unsigned int i)
{
  return i > 0 ? i*factorial(i-1) : 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << factorial(X) << std::endl;
}
```

and I change the value `x` in the factorial.

- When compiling without optimization, the expression is not calculated at compile time.
- When compiling with the `-O1` flag, the expression is still not calculated at compile time.
- With `-O2`, the expression is calculated at compile time if `x < 9`. After this value, the factorial is implemented inline as a loop. Changing the value of `-fconstexpr-depth` flag doesn't change a thing.
- With `-O3`, the expression is calculated at compile time `if x < 7`. After this value, the factorial is implemented inline with x86 xmm extension.
- If I change the product for an sum in the factorial function, I obtain compile time calculation up to `10000` or more and reducing or increasing the value of `-fconstexpr-depth` doesn't change anything.

Does anyone knows what are the rules for gcc 4.7 to implement the recursive function as compile-time or run-time?

Comment: Try `typedef char dummy[factorial(10)]` and see if it compiles. Array sizes must be constant expressions.

Comment: If you check on the bug list of gcc, it contains lots with `constexpr`. I would not rely on `constexpr` being correctly implemented and/or working by gcc (4.7.2 or even 4.8.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constexpr` is only guaranteed to be evaluated at compile-time if it's needed at compile-time. For instance, this is guaranteed to be computed at compile-time, because `enum` values must be constant:

```
enum { VALUE = factorial(X) };
cout << VALUE << endl;
```

In any case where it's not needed at compile-time, it has the same effect as declaring it as `inline`: it's just a hint, and the compiler is free to do what it wants.

Just like `inline`, most compilers nowadays will completely ignore your hint. For performance reasons, the compiler wants to be able to inline things even when you *haven't* asked it to, and has its own algorithm to determine when it is and isn't worthwhile, so why would it bother looking at the `inline` keyword at all?

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a function `constexpr` does not mean that it will be evaluated at compile-time. It means that it can be used to compute a value which is needed at compile-time. In any other context, it's just an ordinary function, and it will be evaluated at runtime unless the compiler determines that evaluating it at compile time satisfies the "as-if" rule, and is worthwhile doing.

In other words, I'd expect you'd find exactly the same pattern of compile-time/run-time execution if you left `constexpr` out of the declaration of the factorial function.